# Retrieve .OST data after harddrive failure

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I want to open an OST file in Outlook 2013. I understand the difference between ost and pst. The reason I need to do this is that after a harddrive failure, I am unable to look at how a user had their local archive set up. I was hoping I could look at a recovered copy of their .OST and see how each of their folders was set to archive.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I am reading differing opinions on whether an OST file can be accessed. TIA

Comment: If you know the difference then you know .OST is just a cache of the server.  Which means however the server is currently configured is how the their folders were setup.

Comment: So there is no way for me to "recreate" the image of the cached info stored in the ost at the time of the crash, preferably offline? Is there some other place that the Outlook client might store archive settings?

Answer (score 0):

This claims `.OST` recovery and further `.ost` to `.pst` conversion. Although I've never bothered to try it. https://www.datanumen.com/exchange-recovery/

Then there's this that might offer something relevant: http://www.howto-outlook.com/tag/data-recovery

It really depends on the kind of data recovery are you trying to perform. Also, were the Outlook settings in question IMAP or POP? What version of Outlook? Are you aware of any more information regarding Outlook?

There may/should be an accessible cloud copy provided it's not an ancient version. If it is, take it from me (I've been in this .OST/.PST situation **many** times) it's not worth the time and effort because, unfortunately, it's a lost cause.